# How to convert dd-mm-yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, oracleclient

convert `dd-mm-yyyy` to `dd/mm/yyyy` for inserting into oracle using oracle client in asp.net

```
string oldstr = TextBox1.Text;
string strDate = DateTime.ParseExact(oldstr, "dd-MM-yyyy", null).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
TextBox4.Text = strDate;
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Maybe you should add your insert code here too... DateTime is a type, the format should be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **c#**

```
DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvarientCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: hi @AjayPunekar i tried ur code like this

   string d = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
    string d1= DateTime.ParseExact(d, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

but still its not working. 
i want this variable to be used in insert stored procedure.

Comment: Thx Ajay.. u helped me alot.. d code below works for me.. thx once more

DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

 string fromDate = dt1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);